# Create a public link that can be placed in an email and when its clicked, it'll change some field values on a specific record

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, marketing-cloud

The marketing manager will send emails to customers. These emails will have links for Opt-In and Opt-Out, These links need to be constructed so when they're clicked, they will update specific fields on the related object in Salesforce. How should I create these links? Is it possible to use Checkboxes instead of links?

Comment: Hi, Veeru, and welcome to SFSE! What have you tried so far? Why the restriction on using Apex Code? Please take the [tour], read about [ask], and then **[edit]** your question with any information you have about what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: @sfdcfox would it be considered as a bad practice if the link makes a call to a gateway endpoint that then calls an apex endpoint and the process gets kicked off to update fields for a specific record and then redirect to a gateway to goes to a front end landing page? instead of VF page + controller? Thanks!

Comment: @sfdcfox In general, in such a case, what are the gotchas? and the thing to avoid? and what are the best practices? Thanks?

Answer (score 2):

First, at least in America, the email you're sending is considered a **marketing email** and **cannot be sent to a customer unless they have already opted in**. Users typically opt in on your website by submitting their information and selecting a check box to be added to a mailing list. **Sending an unsolicited email asking people to opt in is technically against can-spam rules.**

https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business

Second, I don't believe you'll be able to do something like this without Apex; nor should you want to. Emails containing JavaScript are often considered spam for security reasons. **The best you could do is put a link to another page that has the code to set the field.** This page should be a Visualforce page with an apex controller. You would pass an encrypted lead/contact Id as a URL parameter, decrypt it on the page and update the record. Its technically possible to do this with JavaScript as opposed to APEX but that will result in security concerns and still require a development effort for the VF page.

Marketing email is not a new or innovative concept. There are a ton of best practices that you need to consider when implementing email marketing. If you are a smaller company, which I suspect you are, you want to use an established email service as they will be able to help you design a solution that will not violate any laws and help you manage a contact list as well as provide pre-built opt-in/out functionality.

Salesforce offers Marketing cloud for this exact reason.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. we are sending emails through dotmailer to ask customers that you are interested in receiving emails or not. when they open email, two links or buttons. one optin n optout. if customer clicks optin,then it should update in salesforce.

Comment: Right and that is technically illegal in the US. You should seriously read can-spam laws before engaging in marketing email to help protect your company from potential law suits or at the very least, ending up on email black-lists.